# Prove that $f$ is continious at $0$.$f$ is increasing

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, continuity

Let $f:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ be an increasing function. Suppose there are sequences $(x_n)$ and $(y_n)$ such that $x_n<0<y_n$ for all $n\geq1$ And $f(y_n)-f(x_n)\rightarrow0$ as $n \rightarrow\infty$. Prove that $f$ is continious at $0$.

So, I proved (by sandwich theoroem)
$\lim f(x_n)=\lim f(y_n)=f(0)$
And, I think If somehow prove that $(x_n)$and$(y_n)$ or it's subsequence approches $0$
By, sequential criterion we can say that $f$ is continious at $0$ [because $(x_n)$and $(y_n)$are arbritary functions]

Is my thinking correct?And, how can I prove the above?